# Labels on X-Axis bar graph Grafana

Tags: sql, grafana

[image]

Is there a way to add labels to the X-Axis on a bar graph in Grafana or am I simply doing it wrong?

**EDIT** To clarify, the labels should be values from the lob field of my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put ${__cell_0} in "Display name":

[image: Grafana x-lablel modification]

Comment: Unfortunately, that just breaks the graph. It comes back 'No Data' after entering ```${__cell_0}``` in the Display Name field.

Comment: Ok. It looks like if you choose anything other than "Numeric Fields" in Panel->Fields, it will break and render 'No Data" per https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/28060

Switching that along with adding ```${__cell_0}``` fixed it. 

Thanks!